# Poisson and Binomial Distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, poisson-process

I need help with a simple question.

> Suppose that a hairdresser with a single store has 5 customers arrive
>   on average every hour while they are open. Assume that customers’
>   arrivals don’t depend on time of day or on whether other customers
>   have arrived. We wish to model the arrival of customers in the morning
>   (9am to 12 midday). Suppose we define the random variable X as the
>   number of customers arriving in the morning. What would be a suitable
>   distribution for X, along with its mean and variance?
>
> ```
> a) Poisson, lambda = 15; mean = 15; variance = 15;
> b) Poisson, lambda = 15; mean = 15; variance = 225
> c) Binomial, n = 15, p = 0.5; mean = 15; variance = 15  
> d) Binomial, n = 15, p = 0.5; mean = 15; variance = 225
> ```

I know that poisson is used with discreet events. And binomial with continuous events. In this case I would choose a because the mean is equal to the variance. 
Did I choose correctly? or is the case in this question is a special case?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are given an average rate you should use the Poisson distribution. You are correct that the answer is a since the mean is equal to the variance for the Poisson distribution.

Note that the binomial distribution is also discrete, not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{N(t):t\geqslant0\}$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda=5$. Then $Y=N(3)$ which has Poisson distribution with mean $3\cdot5=15$. Since the variance of a Poisson distribution is equal to its mean, the correct choice is a).